# Using an object to replace the switch statement

Tags: javascript

I found the following exemple on the jqfundamentals site. It seems to me that the else statement is unnecessary/wrong. So what am I missing ?

```
var stuffToDo = {
    'bar' : function() {
        alert('the value was bar -- yay!');
    },

    'baz' : function() {
        alert('boo baz :(');
    },

    'default' : function() {
        alert('everything else is just ok');
    }
};

if (stuffToDo[foo]) {
    stuffToDo[foo]();
} else {
    stuffToDo['default']();
}
```

Comment: ehrm.. a `switch` statement would be much, much more convinient for that kind of stuff anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just checking that `stuffToDo[foo]` exists...

and If it doesn't call the `'default'`

Not sure that I think replacing the switch statement is necessary or good, let alone a **fundamental** of javascript...

Answer (score 1):

If `foo` is `"moo"`, then `stuffToDo['default']()` will be invoked (to avoid throwing an exception.)